# invail use of group function

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT department_id, MIN(salary)
FROM employees
WHERE department_id
HAVING AVG(salary) >= (SELECT MAX(AVG(salary))
                       FROM employees
                       GROUP BY department_id);
```

why it give me the invaild use of group function

Comment: The "main" SELECT needs a GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the minimum salary from departments whose average salary is the largest, then change the `having` clause:

```
HAVING AVG(salary) >= (SELECT AVG(salary)
                       FROM employees
                       GROUP BY department_id
                       ORDER BY AVG(salary) DESC
                       LIMIT 1
                      );
```

Answer (score -1):

1. subquery - `MAX(AVG())` you cannot do such a things, dont know what you want to achieve but if you want to hava a max of the departments averages you should do it with

> SELECT MAX(avg_salary) 
>       FROM (SELECT department_id, AVG(salary) AS avg_salary 
>       FROM employees 
>       GROUP BY department_id) AS a;

or easier:

> SELECT TOP 1 AVG(salary) AS avg_salary 
>       FROM employees 
>       GROUP BY department_id
>       ORDER BY AVG(salary) DESC

2. main query - `WHERE department_id` should be specified what values should `department_id` be or `WHERE` clause should be skipped
3. main query - lack of `GROUP BY department_id`
4. but for me this query does not have any sense...I think it would be better if you explained what do you want to calculate, probably it is achivable much easier...